# ABAP logarithm with variable base

Tags: abap, logarithm

do someone know a command or fuction module in ABAP who allows
logarithm a variable to the base of an other variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute it with this logic:

```
DATA: num  TYPE i,
      base TYPE i,
      res  TYPE float.

num = 81.
base = 3.

res = log( num ) / log( base ).
```

The result is 4.

Comment: Thank you, i will use this for my problem.